# C# how tell to one class that it has the same attibutes as another class

Tags: c#, class

I have a class `Person`

```
class Person
{
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

}
public Person(string active, string name, string from, string age, string gender, string country)
{

    Active = active;
    Name = name;
    From = from;
    Age = age;
    Gender = gender;
    Country = country;

}
```

and I have another class called `PersonList`

```
class PersonList : Person
{
}
```

and my class person list must contain one field for **ADD** to my lists view, search for **INDEX**, **NAME** and **ACTIVE** but I don't know how to get the values from the class Person in class PersonList

When I'm in my main script and I try to do this:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PersonList newPerson = new PersonList(
        txtActive.Text,
        txtName.Text,
        txtFrom.Text,
        txtAge.Text,
        txtGender.Text,
        txtCountry.Text);
    if (newPerson.check())
        erase();
}
```

I get one error that tells that PersonList does not contain a constructor that takes 11 Arguments.

Comment: I think you probably want to use `List<Person>` instead of `PersonList`? Other than that your question is very confusing.

Comment: write down a pseudo code...probabably that will help to udnerstand the problem

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis....

Comment: Edited the questions but the parenthesis are not the problem in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, where constructors are implicitly inherited, it's not the same scenario in C#. You need to explicitly tell that you need to inherit the constructor.

In other words create a constructor that accepts 11 arguments and send them back to the base class via `base`

```
public PersonList(string arg1, string arg2...) : base(arg1, arg2...)
```

Comment: But where do you see OP is calling constructor of 11 arguments?? I see only 6 arguments being passed

Comment: Possibly the code is minified to tell the point. 11 or 6, the `PersonList` class in the example does not have any constructor that accepts arguments.

Comment: that worked but can you explain me that? because this is working but i don't know why what *** : base*** is doing?

Comment: i got 11 arguments but i didn't put them all here to make my code shorter

Comment: base refers to the parent class, invoked as function refers to parents class' constructor, in this case refers to `Person`'s constructor. So you do call the `Person`'s constructor with the arguments passed to `PersonList`

Comment: @MárioCorreia, glad I helped. Btw. Not here about the reputation, but not sure if it's ok to accept answer that was wrong by definition and after 3 edits gone right, much after my post was there stating the answer :)

Comment: Pressed by mistake sorry, i don't know why but the answer are allways changing places i accepted your and clicked upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Person {
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public Person(string active, string name, string from, string age, string gender, string country) {
        Active = active;
        Name = name;
        From = from;
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
        Country = country;
    }
}

class PersonList : Person {
        public PersonList(string active, string name, string from, string age, string gender, string country) : base(active, name, from, age, gender, country) {}
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PersonList newPerson = new PersonList(
        txtActive.Text,
        txtName.Text,
        txtFrom.Text,
        txtAge.Text,
        txtGender.Text,
        txtCountry.Text);

    if (newPerson.check())
        erase();
}
```

Comment: thats the code that i have and is giving me problems 
'PersonList' does not contain a constructor that takes 11 arguments Poll2 C:\Poll22\Poll2\Form1.cs

Comment: With your second option i got:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
'Poll2.PersonList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) Poll2 C:\Poll22\Poll2\Form1.cs 129 Active

Comment: you can always pass derived instance in base reference type but not other way around